# How to write/edit Article in Front-end (Publisher)

Tags: joomla

I created a user which is Publisher, then i login to this user, but i don't know how to write/edit Article (in Front-end)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're logged in as a publisher you should get an extra icon in the title of the article which allows you to edit it - assuming your template has these icons in.